# How do I prove the baby is innocent?

Tags: adventure-time-hikwysog

I found Wildberry Princess' Diary and delivered the dessert pizza to get the Receipt, so I can prove two of the three people Lemongrab has taken are innocent. But Peppermint Butler won't sign anything proving their innocence until I can prove all three are innocent.

How do I prove the baby is innocent?

Comment: This suit burns better. Look! LOOK AT BURNS' SUIT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to talk of the Duke of Nuts, his youngest son, Second Nut Son is missing.

He'll provide you with a copy of his Birth Certificate for identification purposes, you can use that as evidence to prove that the baby is in fact a baby.